# Function on_change openerp8 not work

Tags: odoo

I want to add a column where I calculate the sum of the two columns but it doesn't work here is my code

test.py:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class sale_order_line(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'account.bank.statement.line'
_name = 'account.bank.statement.line'
_columns = {
'colx': fields.float(),
'coly': fields.float(),
}
def onchange_result(self, cr, uid, ids, colx, amount, context=None):
    res = {}
    if amount and colx:
        res['coly'] = amount + colx
    return {'value': res}
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
   <data>
      <record model="ir.ui.view" id="account_statement_instructor1_form_viewfzz">
        <field name="name">account.statement.form.viewfzz</field>
        <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_formfz"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='line_ids']/tree/field[@name='date']" position="after">
            <field name="colx" on_change="onchange_result(amount, colx)"/>
            <field name="amount" on_change="onchange_result(amount, colx)"/>
            <field name="coly"/>
           </xpath>
        </field>
      </record></data></openerp>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us how this code isn't working.  What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Wrong order of params: in method colx, params. But on view - amount, colx

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest to use new API, https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#onchange-updating-ui-on-the-fly , as 8.0 supports them

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer in fact I found the solution here it is

Comment: now i have a column with amount  in line_ids in account.bank.statement and i wanna to calcule the sum of this amount.. i tried to use the _get_sum_entry_encoding but i have external error :/..any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class sale_order_line(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'account.bank.statement.line'
_name = 'account.bank.statement.line'
_columns = {
'colx': fields.float(),
'coly': fields.float(),
}
#This method will be called when either the field CostPrice or the field ShippingCost changes.
def on_change_price(self,cr,user,ids,colx,amount,context=None):
#Calculate the total
total = colx + amount
    res = {
        'value': {
    #This sets the total price on the field standard_price.
            'coly': total
      }
}
#Return the values to update it in the view.
return res
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <openerp>
    <data>
      <record model="ir.ui.view" id="account_statement_instructor1_form_viewfzz">
        <field name="name">account.statement.form.viewfzz</field>
        <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_formfz"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='line_ids']/tree/field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
            <field name="colx" on_change="on_change_price(amount,colx)" string="Montant Crédit"/>
            <field name="coly" string="Rest"/>
        </xpath>
        </field>
    </record></data></openerp>
```